# Identify unique observations that satisfy two conditions and then remove R

Tags: r, operators, data.table, grepl

I have a df as follows:

```
data
   names  fruit
7   john  apple
13  john orange
14  john  apple
2   mary orange
5   mary  apple
8   mary orange
10  mary  apple
12  mary  apple
1    tom  apple
6    tom  apple
```

I'd like to do two things. First, count the number of unique observations that have both an apple and an orange (i.e 2 mary and john).

Then after that, I'd like to remove them from my data frame, so that I am left only with unique individuals who got apples only.

This is what I've tried

```
toremove<-unique(data[data$fruit=='apple' & data$fruit=='orange',"names"])  ##this part doesn't work, if it had I would have used the below code to remove the names identified
data2<-data[!data$names %in% toremove,]
```

Really, I wanted to use grepl because my real data are a little more complicated than fruit. This is what I've tried (converted to a data.table first)

```
data1<-data.table(data1)
z<-data1[,ind := grepl('app.*? & orang.*?', fruit), by='names']  ## this works fine when i just use 'app.*?' but collapses when I try to add the & sign, so I'm making an error with the operator. In addition the by='names' doesn't work out for me, which is important. My plan here was to create an indicator (if an individual has an apple and an orange, then they get an indicator==1 and I would then filter them out on the basis of this indicator).
```

So, in summary my problem is in identifying people who have both an apple and an orange. This seems so straightforward, so feel free to direct me to a resource that can teach me this!

**desired output**

```
names fruit
1   tom apple
6   tom apple
```

Comment: So your desired output doesn't include the counts of unique observations? So why are trying to count the in the first place?

Comment: I want to be able to count how many people had both apples and oranges. If i had an indicator for these conditions I would just subset on that and count them. Or, I could limit my df to just people with apples and oranges and count the number of unique people in there. Then when I get the final output of just apple people, a simple subtraction would tell me how many people had both oranges and apples. So really, I'm concentrating on how to identify the apple and orange people. I could work out how to count them after that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only looking for names with `apple`s only, here's a simple `data.table` approach

```
setDT(data)[ , if(all(fruit == "apple")) .SD, by = names]
#    names fruit
# 1:   tom apple
# 2:   tom apple
```

---

For unique observations that have both "apple" and " orange" count, you could do something like

```
data[, any(fruit == "apple") & any(fruit == "orange"), by = names][, sum(V1)]
## [1] 2
```

---

Finally, if all you looking for is the users with only one unique `fruit`, you could try to condition using `uniqueN` from the [devel version on GH](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) (or `length(unique())`)

```
data[, if(uniqueN(fruit) < 2L) .SD, by = names]
#    names fruit
# 1:   tom apple
# 2:   tom apple
```

Comment: the second line of code is great, thank you. The first is nice and simple, but my data are too complex to use it. I amended your second line of code to look like this and it seems to work: data[, any(grepl('app.*?', fruit)) & any(grepl('orang.*?', fruit)), by = names]

Comment: So you can adjust the first line to something like  `setDT(data)[ , if(sum(grepl("apple", fruit)) == .N) .SD, by = names]` too in order to get your desired output

Answer (score 0):

I'm using dplyr package to flag/spot users with oranges and users with both fruits. (I've added an extra row in the end to get a case with orange only).

```
data = 
  read.table(text="
             names  fruit
             7   john  apple
             13  john orange
             14  john  apple
             2   mary orange
             5   mary  apple
             8   mary orange
             10  mary  apple
             12  mary  apple
             1    tom  apple
             6    tom  apple
             21  kathy orange", header=T)

#    names  fruit
# 7   john  apple
# 13  john orange
# 14  john  apple
# 2   mary orange
# 5   mary  apple
# 8   mary orange
# 10  mary  apple
# 12  mary  apple
# 1    tom  apple
# 6    tom  apple
# 21 kathy orange


library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(names) %>%                            # for each user name
  mutate(N_dist = n_distinct(fruit),             # count distinct number of fruits
         N_oranges = sum(fruit=="orange")) %>%   # count number of oranges
  filter(N_oranges == 0 & N_dist < 2) %>%        # keep users with no oranges and no both fruits
  select(names, fruit)


#   names fruit
# 1   tom apple
# 2   tom apple
```

Note that at the point before applying the filter your dataset looks like:

```
#    names  fruit N_dist N_oranges
# 1   john  apple      2         1
# 2   john orange      2         1
# 3   john  apple      2         1
# 4   mary orange      2         2
# 5   mary  apple      2         2
# 6   mary orange      2         2
# 7   mary  apple      2         2
# 8   mary  apple      2         2
# 9    tom  apple      1         0
# 10   tom  apple      1         0
# 11 kathy orange      1         1
```

from where you can get unique names that have both fruits, or users that have oranges.

Comment: You assuming that the values are always are either `apple` or `orange` here. Not to mention that this method will fail for people who have only `orange`

Comment: If there's another fruit the code will exclude users that have 2 out of the 3 fruits. That filter(n>1) does that job. But, indeed it is based on the specific example the user provided.

Comment: Why will it fail for orange only?

Comment: If there is *only* "orange" for a certain name, `n()` will be 1 and it will return false positive

Comment: Yes, you're right. I thought we could return rows with orange only. I missed the part that we need only apples and not just to exclude people with both fruits. Thanks. I'll update....

Comment: @DavidArenburg I still have a feeling that the user just wants to get rid of people that have both fruits. The fact that he says "...apples only" might just refer to his specific example. Not sure if he wants to exclude cases with oranges only. Can he clarify that please?

Comment: there will certainly be people in the df who just have oranges only. I'm glad you brought this up, as I will need to get rid of those too. My main concern was with the identify the users of apples AND oranges though, as I wasn't able to get the code right. I will be able to mange getting rid of users of oranges (sole users) in a separate step by myself.